# How to pass a smart pointer to a function as void*?

Tags: c++, function, smart-pointers

There are some functions using `void *` as their parameters, how to pass a smart pointer into it in this case?

For example I have

```
gboolean callback(gpointer arg); // might delete arg when it finish

A *mydata = new A();
gpointer parg = (gpointer)mydata;
g_timeout_add(100, callback, parg);
```

What if I use smart pointer here:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> mydata(new A());
```

How to convert it to arg of `g_timeout_add(.., void*)`?

Comment: If callback deletes your pointer then you are in trouble.

Comment: Make sure you never pass the pointer to a function that might delete the pointer. When the smart pointer gets destroyed it will also delete the pointer, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think `mydata.get()` can't be used here, as the smart pointer might be freed before the callback is invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume from your title that `gpointer` is actually `void*`. In that case I'll also assume that when you say `might delete arg when it finish` you really mean `free()` because once you've thrown away the original type you can't guarantee that a `delete` would be legal.

In that case, under no circumstances should you use a smart pointer to pass to the `g_timeout_add` call because it will potentially result in both the callback and the smart pointer both deleting the same memory, which is then undefined behavior.

You need to decide who owns the `mydata`: The caller, the callback, or shared. Then based on that you can implement the caller/callback code to properly represent those ownership semantics.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly that I need to explicitly call `delete`/`free` in this case, I thought I can somehow use smart pointer to avoid potential memory leak here.